# How can I launch node server and open localhost in the browser after there?

Tags: linux, bash

I have the simple node.js project and script on the bash. I use a few commands before launching the server and after there I need to open browser on the localhost.
bash script:

```
nodemon server.js
xdg-open https://localhost:3007
```

How can I launch node server and open localhost in the browser after there?

Comment: `nodemon server.js &`  maybe?

Comment: @Jetchisel, nodemon server.js command launches only server without opening in the browser

Comment: So nodemon does not have a builtin browser?

Comment: @Александр - have you actually tried adding the ampersand behind server.js in your script? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install open module:

```
npm install open
```

Add to the server.js:

```
const open = require('open');
open('http://localhost:3007');
```

Launch project:

```
npm start
```

Node server was started  and open browser on the http://localhost:3007

Comment: This requires you to modify your production code. What happens on servers without GUI?

Answer (score 0):

You can open `nodemon` in the background and then open the browser:

```
nodemon server.js &
xdg-open https://localhost:3007
```

Or as a single line, it doesn't make any difference:

```
nodemon server.js & xdg-open https://localhost:3007
```

Comment: nodemon server.js command launches only the server without opening in the browser

Comment: @Александр yes, that's why the next command is `xdg-open`. Since the first command is executed in the background, the second program will be started immediately. Have you actually typed/pasted the two commands into your terminal?